# How to use multiple LDR to trigger a led?

Tags: ldr

Whats the best way to use multiple LDRs to power up an LED? Currently I’m using one LDR which turns on an LED when it senses light. But now I want to use three LDRs (at different locations) to trigger the same LED. The LED should turn on when any of the three LDRs sense light. 
Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: Hi, so how do you do it with one LDR? (Please edit your question to include a schematic of that, even if you think it's obvious!) What have you considered to solver your problem this far?

Comment: Have you tried putting the 3 LDRs in parallel ?

Comment: Based on my searchs when using LDRs in parallel light should hit all of LDRs to turn on the LED.

Comment: @user7196028 This is not true. By putting 3 LDRs in parallel, if only one "sees" a light source, thus reducing its resistance, then the equivalent resistor is somewhat lower than the lowest resistor. For example, lets say we have 2 resistors of 1MΩ and 1kΩ. The equivalent resistance is \$\frac{10^9 \cdot 10^3}{10^9 + 10^3} = 999.999 Ω \$.

Comment: @Sparky256 - On the contrary it is very much a duplicate.  Both questions are mistaken attempts to solve the same problem of building a lasertag game.  Neither will work *for precisely the same reason* - no optical sensor is going to solve this problem unless the output is fed into a detector looking for a pattern, and rejecting ambient interference.

Comment: @ChrisStratton. Based on your observation and conclusion that both designs are much too simplistic to work (and after review I agree) I am VTC.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to put the LDRs in parallel, as @thece suggests. This may cause some cross-influencing (ambient light on one LED influeneces the trigger point of the other LEds).

Slightly more involved: repeat the circuit LDR-R2-Q1 for each location, and connect the collectors of the transistors (R1-LED only once, LED connects to all 3 transistors).

---

For a very crude lasertag you might simply put LDRs in parallel, but I am not sure that hitting a single LDR (on a moving target!) with a laser (very small beam) is feasible.

Practical laser-tag systems use the laser only for the show effect: the real targeting is done with a (focused) IR beam, and the detectors are TSOP-style receivers for (modulated!) IR light. Very efficient, cheap, and high ambient-light suppression. It is exactly the way a TV IR remote works. And the IR signal contains the identity of the gun, so the victim's hardware can detect who hit him.

Fun note: the desire to build a laser-tag system is what dragged me into micro-controllers some 20 years ago. (The PIC 16C84 had just become available, bot no cheap proggers, so I had to make one, and no cheap HLL, so I had to make one, and not available in my country, so I started a webshop...) [Dave Bodger's laser tag FAQ](http://www.lasertag.co.uk/PDF_files/sgconst.pdf) is still online!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can use only one circuit because i want to make lazertag sensors for player's vest and headband (for example 8 ldrs), so repeating circuit per LDRs is not reasonable. i think if i put LDRs in parallel and then light hits a LDR other LDR's resist is constant therefore resistanse of whole LDRs causes LED dont turn on. ( excuseme for my bad english and electronic informaton)

Comment: Wouter van Bodger sounds better LOL +1