# How to use 8 IR receives that when one of them sense IR turn on a LED?

Tags: infrared

I want to use 8 IR sensors (4 on front of vest, 2 on back and 2 on headband like lazertag vest) that when each of sensors hit by IR, turn on a led. I don't want to use any microcontroller so a simple circuit is what I want.
I can achieve this by one IR receiver but I want to use 8 sensor. Help me please.[image]

Comment: You should probably use demodulating IR detectors and a modulated source.  If your detectors are open-collector (ie, require a pullup resistor) you can probably wire-OR them (connect all the outputs together with one pullup resistor).  You'll then likely need a pulse-stretcher circuit.  555 ones may be easiest to find though the power consumption is a bit high.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Can you add a schematic of the circuit you have that works? Please capitalise your words properly.

Comment: If you have one circuit working then what's stopping you making eight?

Comment: Please, clarify - do you want _one_ LED light up when _all_ sensors were hit, _one_ LED light up when _either_ sensor is hit, or one LED _per each_ sensor? The question seems to describe first, but the title implies second.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple LDR to trigger a led?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392612/how-to-use-multiple-ldr-to-trigger-a-led) .  You seem to have two questions aimed at the same underlying need, so please explain what you are actually trying to *accomplish*.  It's relatively unlikely that either approach, or any approach using *umodulated* sources will work well in practice.

Comment: I want one LED light up when IR hits one sensor. For example: when IR hits one of headband's sensors the LED light up. Same as this for other sensors on vest and headband.

Comment: *None* of these ideas will work well without modulated sources and detectors that detect that modulation.  Further, you need to "stretch" the pulse of a brief hit to a longer-duration lighting of the indicator.  Realistically while you can do that with something like a 555, using an MCU will let you have a flashing indicator pattern, modulate your transmitter, create sound effects, and implement usual rules like having a player "time out" after n hits before their emitter works again.  Transmitting a unique data pattern will also let you avoid self-hits from reflection.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have enough budget. Maybe it is unusual but I develope an android app that calculates health and ammo and other things (I don't want to make a pro lazertag system) So I only need to help me about my question no more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The English word "I" is always capitalized.  That's such a simple and universal rule that there is no excuse for getting it wrong repeatedly.  That's showing contempt for the volunteers here that you seek a favor from.

Comment: The point is that a low-end microcontroller is the *cheapest* way to do the *complete* task.  Given you have no electrical interface to the phone, you need to get things in human-scale timeframes first, and that's where the MCU helps you.

Comment: Thanks for all comments but please answer my question. All comments have focused on lazertag system but my questin is another thing. Please answer my question.

Comment: All responses have focused on a lazertag-type system *because that's specifically what you asked a question about*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but your schematic can be considered only to be a concept drawing without any actual circuit details. As a drawing of an electronic circuit it's never going to work.

I bet you are not gaming in darkness. In daylight or under lamps there's plenty of other IR radiation which your circuit must be able to ignore. You need a recognizable modulation in the transmitted IR. Your receiver must be able to filter what IR radiation detectors (photodiodes or phototransistors) output, recognize the right code and trigger the action that is wanted. Detecting only the IR radiation strength needs full darkness.

I recommend you to search for IR remote contol receiving ICs such as TDA8160 by SGS-Thomson. It can have several IR photodiodes in parallel. It detects no special complex codes, only pulses which have high enough repetition frequency.

A little more sophisticated signal is used in IRM-2638T by Everlight. It needs pulses which have the right frequency. The sensor and pulse frequency detection circuit are integrated, so you need many of them for one person. But the outputs are easily combined.

If you search a little, you'll find more.

BTW. Your schematic shows that you need a competent partner for circuit details and tests.

Comment: Thanks guys for all comments. I decided to use a remote control as gun and TSOP1837 for IR reciever on vest and headband